# MemoryError in the Nim Sum game on Leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the following problem from https://leetcode.com/problems/nim-game/description/:

> You are playing the following Nim Game with your friend: There is a heap of stones on the table, each time one of you take turns to remove 1 to 3 stones. The one who removes the last stone will be the winner. You will take the first turn to remove the stones.
>
> Both of you are very clever and have optimal strategies for the game. Write a function to determine whether you can win the game given the number of stones in the heap.
>
> For example, if there are 4 stones in the heap, then you will never win the game: no matter 1, 2, or 3 stones you remove, the last stone will always be removed by your friend.

I came up with the following solution, using a bottom-up dynamic programming approach:

```
class Solution(object):
    def canWinNim(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if n <= 3:
            return True
        win = [None for _ in range(n+1)]
        win[1] = win[2] = win[3] = True
        for n in range(4, n+1):
            win[n] = not all([win[n-i] for i in [1, 2 ,3]])
        return win[n]
```

However, when I try to submit this, I get a `MemoryError`:

[image]

Since the exact test case for which this `MemoryError` arises is not given, I'm struggling to see what is causing the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you use range .. are you on python 3 or 2?

Comment: You assume you can hold in memory the solution for every game up to and including n. This being a competitive site (I assume), they're not going to give you small numbers like a million.

Comment: Instead of generating the solution for every game up to n maybe you could try to generate one for let's say up to 20, examine it and see if you can spot a pattern. If there's one you could exploit it to generate solution for n without having to generate all the other solutions up to n-1.

Comment: What is line 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as pointed out by Kenny Ostrom, probably the test cases are for such large `n` that there is insufficient memory to store the answers generated in the 'bottom up' dynamic programming approach. By running it on a smaller example, I noticed that the answer is simply

```
bool(x % 4)
```